# When I minimize the page div extends to match margin property

Tags: html, css, margin

So, I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong here.
The divs are extending to match the margin property from CSS code when I zoom-out the page to 25%.

Link to the [website](http://dellycah.netii.net/)

I wanted it to go more like this square-shaped content(if you get what I mean): 
[goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz4kg.png)

**Here's a snippet from the css file:**

```
.post{
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 250;
    margin-top: 10;
    margin-bottom: 10;
    background-color: rgba(188, 64, 119, 0.4);
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 40;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="post">
            <img id="cat" src="Imgs/cat.png" alt="cat-logo"/>
            <!-- text -->
</div>
```

I'm new to this, so... be patient, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this to your rule :

```
max-width: 970px;
margin: 10px auto;
```

If you define a `max-width` the container can't take more than this value.
So now you have to center your container with `margin` auto on left and right.

Comment: Don't forget +1 and check button on the left to validate response if this solve your problem !

Comment: It says I can't change the publicly displayed post score 'till I get a 15 reput. I'll make sure it changes when that happens. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using unitless margin s on `.post` - that's bad practice. Use some sort of relative unit, like %. If you change `.post { margin: 25; }` to `.post { margin: 25%; }` the margins don't act weird when you zoom in/out.